# Change language/locale of installed brew packages

Tags: macos, localization, homebrew

Some terminal programs (e.g., `R`, `nvim`) I install by using `brew` are using German rather than English, which is the main language set for my Mac.

Since this happens only for programs installed via `brew`: How can I change the language of my `brew` installs?

The output of `locale` on my system is:

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting LANG in your profile will give you the language you want, for example:
`LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`